# Use regex to isolate information in filename

Tags: python, regex

I have various files that are formatted like so;

```
file_name_twenty_135032952.txt
```

where `file_name_twenty` is a description of the contents, and `13503295` is the id. 
I want two different regexes; one to get the description out of the filename, and one to get the id.

Here are some other rules that the filenames follow:

- The filename will never contains spaces, or uppercase characters
- the id will always come directly before the extension
- the id will always follow an underscore
- the description may sometimes have numbers in it; for example, in this filename: `part_1_of_file_324980332.txt`, `part_1_of_file` is the description, and `324980332` is the id.

I've been toiling for a while and can't seem to figure out a regex to solve this. I'm using python, so any limitations thereof with its regex engine follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsplit` once on an underscore and to remove the extension from `id`.

```
s = "file_name_twenty_13503295.txt"

name, id = s.rsplit(".",1)[0].rsplit("_", 1)

print(name, id)

file_name_twenty 13503295
```

Comment: Oh. I guess I was focused too much on making a regex that I forgot about split.

Comment: @Maurdekye, split should be sufficient as your file names have repeating patterns.